# Crystal Reports External Join

Tags: join, oracle11g, crystal-reports, command, datasource

I have 2 data sources that I am querying, then joining in Crystal Reports on a key string with a Left Outer Join.  The intent of the report is to identify purchases made that were not processed.  The issue is that CR refuses to show the matching right query records.

- Data Source 1: Excel worksheet on my local machine containing raw
  credit card purchases.  "Left table"
- Data Source 2: 2 subqueries from a hosted Oracle database with a
  Union join containing processed credit card transactions.  "Right
  table"
- Key String: The last 4 digits of a credit card number concatenated
  with the date-time of the transaction, e.g. "223402-06-2019 04:15:00"

The queries return proper values when executed separately.  I have verified that many records returned for the Left table actually do have matching Right table records that are not displayed.  I did this using a separate report showing only the Right table query results and manually searching for different key strings.

I'm completely buffaloed and any assistance would be appreciated.

The SQL from Crystal Reports:

```
I:\Dept\DCS\MPOOL\Fleet Management Data\M5\M5 Automation Data Tables\ComData Transaction Data.xls
`SELECT DISTINCT CD.`First Name` AS UNIT_NO,
CD.`HIERARCHY LEVEL3` AS USE_DEPT,
DATEVALUE(MONTH(CD.`Transaction Date`) & "/" & DAY(CD.`Transaction Date`) & "/" & YEAR(CD.`Transaction Date`)) + TIMEVALUE(HOUR(CD.`Transaction Time`) & ":" & MINUTE(CD.`Transaction Time`) & ":" & SECOND(CD.`Transaction Time`)) AS TRANS_DT, 
CD.`Odometer` AS ODOMETER,
CD.`Card Number` AS CARD_NO,
RIGHT(CD.`Card Number`, 4) & FORMAT(DATEVALUE(MONTH(CD.`Transaction Date`) & "/" & DAY(CD.`Transaction Date`) & "/" & YEAR(CD.`Transaction Date`)) + TIMEVALUE(HOUR(CD.`Transaction Time`) & ":" & MINUTE(CD.`Transaction Time`) & ":" & SECOND(CD.`Transaction Time`)), "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss") AS KEYSTRING
FROM `Sheet1$` CD
WHERE ISDATE(CD.`Transaction Date`) AND CD.`Transaction Date` >= FORMAT('02/01/2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy') AND CD.`Transaction Date` <= FORMAT('02/15/2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy')
EXTERNAL JOIN Command.KEYSTRING={?m5oksr: Command_1.KEYSTRING}


m5oksr
SELECT DISTINCT TCC.UNIT_NO,
VUDC.USING_DEPT_NO AS USE_DEPT,
TCC.ISSUE_DT + 2/24 AS TRANS_DT,
TCC.NEW_METER AS ODOMETER,
'COMP' AS STATUS,
TCC.CARD_NO AS CARD_NO,
SUBSTR(TCC.CARD_NO, 16, 4) || TO_CHAR(TCC.ISSUE_DT + 2/24, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS KEYSTRING,
FROM MFIVE.VIEW_TRIPCARD_COMPLETED_TRANS TCC
LEFT OUTER JOIN VIEW_UNIT_DEPT_COMP VUDC ON TCC.COMPANY = VUDC.COMPANY and TCC.UNIT_NO = VUDC.UNIT_NO
WHERE TCC.ISSUE_DT + 2/24 >= TO_DATE('02/01/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TCC.ISSUE_DT + 2/24 <= TO_DATE('02/15/2019 11:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT IR.FIELD2 as UNIT_NO,
VUDC.USING_DEPT_NO AS USE_DEPT,
TO_DATE(IR.FIELD1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24 AS TRANS_DT,
IR.METER as ODOMETER,
'FAIL' AS STATUS,
NVL2(IR.FIELD27, CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-', SUBSTR(IR.FIELD27,-4)),'') as CARD_NO,
SUBSTR(NVL2(IR.FIELD27, CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-', SUBSTR(IR.FIELD27,-4)),''), 16, 4) || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(IR.FIELD1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS KEYSTRING,
FROM INTERFACE_REJECT IR
INNER JOIN INTERFACE_STAT ST ON IR.COMPANY = ST.COMPANY and IR.STAT_ID = ST.STAT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP_MAIN E ON IR.COMPANY = E.COMPANY AND IR.FIELD29 = E.TRIPCARD_PIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN VIEW_UNIT_DEPT_COMP VUDC ON IR.COMPANY = VUDC.COMPANY and IR.FIELD2 = VUDC.UNIT_NO
WHERE LENGTH(IR.FIELD1) = 19 AND ST.INTERFACE_NAME = 'M5-TRIP-CARD-INTF' AND TO_DATE(IR.FIELD1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24 >=TO_DATE('02/01/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(IR.FIELD1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 2/24 <= TO_DATE('02/15/2019 11:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
EXTERNAL JOIN Command_1.KEYSTRING={?I:\Dept\DCS\MPOOL\Fleet Management Data\M5\M5 Automation Data Tables\ComData Transaction Data.xls: Command.KEYSTRING}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the join works? If the join doesn't work then you will get nulls and my guess is that this is what is happening. Try to use INNER JOIN instead of Lef join and check if there are any rows returned. If records are returned you may need to cast the values to the same type and trim them. It is possible that the value returned by excel has empty spaces or different value type, which Crystal converts incorrectly

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I am sure the join works.  After a bit of tinkering the report now returns a single (1) match out of the hundreds that exist.  Are you suggesting using an INNER JOIN where the EXTERNAL is now?  What is the syntax for an external inner join?  As for the values being returned by Excel, I have browsed them from the field and found them patterned identically to those from the Oracle database.